# How do I modify/override variables inherited from a Groovy base script?

Tags: java, variables, inheritance, groovy

When creating a Groovy base script, and then extending that base script, why isn't it possible to modify/override the value of inherited instance variables?

Normally when extending a class in Groovy or Java, as long as the variable is accessible to the child class and not final it can be modified by that child class. However, when extending a base script in Groovy the child class can read inherited variables and assign values to them with no complaints from the compiler but whenever other methods access the variable they get the value that was set in the parent class.

I've tried using static and instance blocks to assign values to the variables and neither one seems to work.

The following script is an example that will run in the GroovyConsole. The only way I've been able to override the value of an inherited variable is to re-declare the variable.

```
abstract class MyScript extends Script
{
    public String k1 = "v1"

    public void test()
    {
        println k1
    }
}

abstract class MyScriptExtended extends MyScript
{
    // public String k1 = "v4" //<-- Have to re-declare the k1 variable to override the value from MyScript

    public MyScriptExtended() 
    {
        this.k1 = "v4"
    }

    public void test()
    {
        println "The value of k1 is $k1"
    }
}

@BaseScript(MyScriptExtended)
import groovy.transform.BaseScript

test()
```

My goal is to have a set of common variables that will be used in classes that extend my base script but they also need to be able to override the values of those variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the way Script are parsed in Groovy using `@BaseScript` or `GroovyShell`, you can't modify the value of a variable declared in parent script class.

So either you have to override the getter for the property or redeclare it in your child script class.

Another thing that you can do is, instead of using `@BaseScript` to execute script methods, you can create a new instance of child script and then call the methods on its object.

Comment: would setting the base script in the compiler configuration work the same way?